# to create a color genarator using for loop and appendChild

Tags: javascript

```
const containerEl = document.querySelector (".container")

for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    const colorContainerEl =document.createElement("div")
    colorContainerEl.classList.add("color-container");
    containerEl.appendChild("colorContainerEl");
    
}
```

```
const containerEl = document.querySelector (".container")

for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    const colorContainerEl =document.createElement("div")
    colorContainerEl.classList.add("color-container");
    containerEl.appendChild("colorContainerEl");
    
}
```

don't know what is wrong with this .it Shows mew this error messagese

Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object.

Comment: There's a typo. `containerEl.appendChild("colorContainerEl");` is done on string. It should be  `containerEl.appendChild(colorContainerEl);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `colorContainerEl` variable.

```js
const containerEl = document.querySelector (".container")

for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    const colorContainerEl = document.createElement("div")
    colorContainerEl.classList.add("color-container");
    containerEl.appendChild(colorContainerEl);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you were getting that error message because you were appending a string `"colorContainerEl"` rather than the object `colorContainerEl`

I rebuilt your fixed code (as @Nishanth shows) in a way that shows the `<div>`'s in a visual manner so that you can see it is working:

```js
const containerEl = document.querySelector (".container")

for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    const colorContainerEl =document.createElement("div");
    colorContainerEl.innerHTML = `div ${index}`
    colorContainerEl.classList.add("color-container");
    containerEl.appendChild(colorContainerEl);
    
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.color-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #0ee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```